# Javascript: Instantiating new object from it's own recursion

Tags: javascript, object

I'd like to be able to create a function that returns a grid of parameter defined size and inserts parameter defined data into the grid's 'cubbies'. For instance:

```
function createGrid(rows, cols, data){

var customGrid = [];

//create grid
for(row=0;row<rows;row++){
       var customRow = [];
       for(col=0;col<cols;col++){ 

               //dataFunction can accept different types of data
               if(typeof dataFunction == 'function'){//alert("was function");
                    data = dataFunction();
               }
               //Here lies our problem, I think:
               else if(typeof dataFunction == 'object'){alert("was object");
                   data = new dataFunction(); alert("was object");
               }

               else{//alert("was else");
                   data = dataFunction;
               }

             customRow.push(data);

       }
       customGrid.push(customRow);
}

return customGrid;

}
```

Furthermore, I'd like to be able to call createGrid() on itself so that we can have grids within grids. Something like this:
    createGrid(1,2,createGrid(2,2,createObj))

When I do this, the first grid (the 2x2 with an obj inside) is called and successfully creates a new 2x2 grid, each with a unique object. I would like this process to repeat itself for the next 'cubby' of the larger grid (the 1x2 grid), but instead since it is now fed (via dataFunction) an object, it just provides a reference to the first grid in the next cubby.

What I would like:

```
-------------
||obj1|obj2||
||---------||
||obj3|obj4||
-------------
||obj5|obj6||
||---------||
||obj7|obj8||
-------------
```

What happens instead:

```
-------------
||obj1|obj2||
||---------||
||obj3|obj4||
-------------
||obj1|obj2||
||---------||
||obj3|obj4||
-------------
```

I'm hoping there is a way to re-instantiate dataFunction so that the next iteration of the larger grid called a whole new version of itself so that the second 'cubby' contained a whole new grid.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code uses `dataFunction` without defining it anywhere or accepting it as an argument. Where/how does the code get it?

Comment: What happens if you define a grid first and the pass it to the next function?

Comment: to TJ Crowder, that was a mistake in my typing above. data in the parameter should read as "dataFunction", which then gets written to variable "data". Good catch. @Derylius, You are right that we could just make the entire grid and then pass that as an object through again (without employing recursion). That solution would work, but I find having the single function, with the ability to handle recursive calls would be more elegant. As this is more hobby than work, it's not too costly to sacrifice time for elegance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something like this: `createGrid(1,2,createGrid(2,2,createObj))` - [but] it just provides a reference to the first grid in the next cubby.

Same problem as [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317902/1048572): You're passing a reference to the one constructed grid, which will then be referenced from all new cubbies - it will `alert("was object")`; and objects are copied by reference.

If you want an instantiation to happen for each constructed cell, then you will need to pass a function for the `dataFunction` parameter again:

```
createGrid(1,2,function() {
    return createGrid(2,2,createObj);
})
```

---

Also notice that `if (typeof dataFunction == 'object') data = new dataFunction();` is rubbish. You can use `new` only on constructor functions, whose `typeof` is `'function'`. Otherwise (when `dataFunction` is not constructable) it would throw an exception.

Comment: I figured the check for object and trying to instantiate with "new dataFunction()" would be garbage. I thought I may be falling into the same trap, and I tried creating an external function that returned the grid (similar to last time), but I think I kept using the word "new" and it would throw it away. This (again) works of course, so thank you (again).